# How to change font color of google maps marker clusterer

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

Could anybody please tell me how to change the font color of a markerclusterer marker. This is my current code for styling the marker

```
mcOptions = {styles: [{
                height: 27,
                url: "image.png",
                width: 35
                }],
                maxZoom: 8
                }

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

Comment: @VikasGhodke I did read the doc, that's how i've managed to get as far as i have with it. I missed `textColor` i must have been 'word blind' :). This fixed it, if you put it as an answer i will mark it as correct to help future users, as there is not currently a question of this nature

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check this Documentation for **[Marker Clusterer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering)** under class ClusterIconStyle

There is an option named `textColor` which sets the color of the label text shown on the cluster icon.

Comment: Thats what I wanted! :) 10x!

Comment: Updated the broken link (2017)

Comment: @BrettGregson i think this is right link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html

Comment: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html

Comment: `textColor` doesn't seems to exists in the latest version anymore. Somebody have an Idea of the new solution?

Answer (score 16):

[A working JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/zrk7f2yf/2/) to change the font properties of the clustermarker. Below is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MarkerClusterer v3 Simple Example</title>
    <style >
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 20px 20px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      #map-container {
        padding: 6px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
        width: 600px;
      }
      #map {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/data.json"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>

    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
              dataPhoto.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var mcOptions = {
            //imagePath: 'https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/images/m',
          styles:[{

          url: "https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/images/m1.png",
                width: 53,
                height:53,
                fontFamily:"comic sans ms",
                textSize:15,
                textColor:"red",
                //color: #00FF00,
          }]

        };
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>A simple example of MarkerClusterer (100 markers)</h3>
    <div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the [API reference link](http://web.archive.org/web/20160122183325/http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html) for more options and customizations.

Comment: Thank you for the web archive reference link. The [reference page](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) that was ported to GitHub seems to have been truncated part of the way down.

Comment: your fiddle did not help me but i used your code to solve my problem. Thanks. var mcOptions = {
            //imagePath: 'https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/images/m',
          styles:[{

          url: "https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/images/m1.png",
                width: 53,
                height:53,
                fontFamily:"comic sans ms",
                textSize:15,
                textColor:"red",
                //color: #00FF00,
          }]

        };

Answer (score 5):

You can pass just one element in `styles` option, like this

```
var options = {
    maxZoom: 15,
    styles:[{
        url: 'https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/images/m1.png',
        width: 53,
        height: 53,
        textColor: '#fff',
    }]

};
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, options);
```

but in this case you will have one img for all cluster sizes (1-10-100).
Better to pass 5 elements. One for each cluster size, but it's too many rows of code (I've 3 clusterers on the map).

So for me works this

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
    imagePath: 'https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/images/m',  
    maxZoom: 15  
});
mc.setStyles(mc.getStyles().map(function (style) {
    style.textColor = '#fff';
    return style;
}));
mc.addMarkers(markers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Bitmap makeIcon(String text, int textColor) {
    ensureViewsSetUp();
    if (mTextView != null) {
        mTextView.setText(text);
        mTextView.setTextColor(textColor);
    }
    return makeIcon();
}
```

On google map there are clusters and by default the cluster background color is blue and text (number) color is white,
if you want to change that text color then you need change in this method of `IconGenerator.java`

Comment: please write some description for your answer. the OP should know about your codes. thanks.